# How to create type definitions in your local project for a javascript library?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to use the [N3](https://github.com/rdfjs/N3.js) library in a typescript project. The example javascript code on the README looks like this.

```
const N3 = require('n3');
const { DataFactory } = N3;
const { namedNode, literal, defaultGraph, quad } = DataFactory;
const myQuad = quad(
  namedNode('https://ruben.verborgh.org/profile/#me'),
  namedNode('http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/givenName'),
  literal('Ruben', 'en'),
  defaultGraph(),
);
```

In typescript I'm stuck at the first step. In the root of my project I have a file named main.ts with the following.

```
import * as N3 from "n3";
```

But I get an error "Could not find a declaration file for module 'n3'"

Here's where I'm stuck. The type definitions in DefinitelyTyped are old and out of date so I can't use them. I'm trying to create my own type definitions for the library, but I can't figure out how to do this. Is it possible to create a type definition file that resides in my local project (i.e. not in node_modules?). I've tried to do this in several ways without success. Is there a way to do this? What is the right way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a module declaration for `n3` in a separate file that will be included at compile time (e.g. a `.d.ts` file).

```
declare module 'n3' {
   export interface Foo {} // replace with real interface/method declarations.
}
```

A common pattern is to declare things using a namespace then export the namespace as the module. This allows types to be referenced from the namespace without having to import anything.

```
declare namespace N3 {
    interface Foo {} // replace with real interface/method declarations.
}

declare module 'n3' {
    export = N3;
}
```

Now you can reference the type via an import statement, or directly from the namespace.

```
import {Foo} from 'n3'; // Import type from module
let foo:N3.Foo = {}; // Use type directly from namespace
```

Comment: When I try the first one I get this error, "[ts] Invalid module name in augmentation. Module 'n3' resolves to an untyped module at './/node_modules/n3/N3.js', which cannot be augmented."